# Using ArcPy to find Enhanced Metafile (EMF) graphics added to ArcMap layout?

Tags: arcpy, arcmap, emf

Enhanced metafile graphics can be added to maps manually but how can you manipulate them with ArcPy when this code finds no elements?

```
mxd = arcpy.mapping.MapDocument("CURRENT")
#Report picture elements
if len(arcpy.mapping.ListLayoutElements(mxd, "PICTURE_ELEMENT")) > 0:   
    for elm in arcpy.mapping.ListLayoutElements(mxd, "PICTURE_ELEMENT"):
        print elm.name
#Report graphic elements
if len(arcpy.mapping.ListLayoutElements(mxd, "GRAPHIC_ELEMENT")) > 0:      
    for elm in arcpy.mapping.ListLayoutElements(mxd, "GRAPHIC_ELEMENT"):
        print elm.name
```

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE!  As a new user be sure to take the [Tour] to learn about our focussed Q&A format.  What does `for elm in arcpy.mapping.ListLayoutElements(mxd)` and then iterating to print `elm.name` for each report?  What were the precise steps that you used to add your EMF to your map manually?

Comment: The emf graphics elements were added from a file to an ArcMap map using menu -Insert-Picture.    These were simple vector graphics.                                                               eml is a variable to receive an element object . The first use in code attempts to find picture elements in the project, the 2nd use attempts to find any graphic elements. emf graphics added manually are not found by either - though they are selectable and are saved with the ArcMap project

Comment: Has the EMF been saved into your MXD before creating your MapDocument object?

Comment: The emf were not initially in the map project but after addition they appear either by reference or (selectable) are saved in the project. They must therefore appear somewhere in the project description that ArcMap saves

Comment: People sometimes get confused when using "CURRENT".  Have you tried closing ArcMap and then running your script outside of it from say IDLE by referencing the MXD by its full pathname?

Comment: Cross-posted as https://stackoverflow.com/q/48783678/820534

Answer (score 1):

Your code should work and show the emf-files, which are of the type `“PICTURE_ELEMENT”`. So make sure, that your script runs in ArcMap from your opend MXD containing the emf-files. You could also execute your code in the Python Window of ArcMap to check your code. At least you can build the mxd object using the path to your mxd-file: `mxd = arcpy.mapping.MapDocument(path_to_your_mxd_file)`.

Comment: Do you mean that reference in my code to the loaded "Current" project is not sufficient but you must point to the file specifically?

Comment: Yes that direct and specific reference to the file rather than to the "Current" solved the problem and how it finds the elements - thank you

Comment: @RegWatson You should now be able to restart ArcMap and use "CURRENT" to find it using your original code.

Comment: OK, it seems that pictures pasted into the Data View may be selectable there but cannot be found by that code, but if they are pasted into the Layout View and the project saved then ArcPy will find them

Comment: Yes, that is true. The ListLayoutElements method has only access to the Layout View. Another indicator for that (beside the word Layout inside the method name), is the missing parameter for specifying the data frame.

Comment: Do you have any code demonstrating accessing these type of picture elements in the Data View? Or a link to a reference? I would find it better working in that view where the x and y are in map units rather than cm

Comment: sorry, no I don't.

Comment: My understanding is that picture (and all map surround) elements only exist in layouts (Layout View).  There is at least one Q&A here that provides code for converting between page and map units in layouts.

Comment: I have been able to add vector elements from emf files to either the Data View or the Layout View and they appear to be independent (as expected). The only ones that the Arcpy seems to find are those added to the Layout view. It seems that accessing those in the Data View requires an unknown approach. I have to place them in the Layout View via the menu (cannot do it by code yet) and as yet I have not been able to modify the properties of picture elements via ArcPy even when I can list them. Therefore I have no functionality yet.